# How to exclude customHeaders for selected components in karma?

Tags: javascript, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, karma-mocha, gulp-karma

```
customHeaders: [{
  match: 'context.html', => customContextFile
  name: 'Content-Security-Policy',
  value: 'default-src 'none'; connect-src 'self';'
}]
```

This customHeaders is getting added to all the components while testing and I want to exclude this customHeaders for selected components, I don't want to exclude the components from karma.conf.js.

I need to exclude this CSP headers for selected components, without removing them from testing.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.